# Access ABAP CDS View from Cloud HANA DB

Tags: hana, sap-erp, cds

I'm using SAP Cloud HANA Database for an application. And here I need to access ABAP CDS Views which I created in the ERP system from the cloud HANA database.
Currently what I'm doing is replicating the required ERP (SAP) tables in the cloud database eg: **mara, ekpo ,eket** (with required columns) .

Assume that I've created a ABAP CDS view in ERP with the required information. And how can I consume it from the cloud HANA DB.

I've searched a lot but found nothing.

Comment: what do you mean by "consume"? you are building native HANA XS app or wanna join two data sources (ERP+HANA) in a single select?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create OData service from that CDS view in ERP side. After that, you can use that service in your cloud app.

You may want to check these links:

[Creating OData service from CDS view.](https://blogs.sap.com/2015/04/20/creating-odata-services-out-of-cds-views/)

[ABAP CDS views using SAP Cloud Platform.](https://blogs.sap.com/2018/04/07/visualize-s4hana-cloud-abap-cds-views-using-sap-cloud-platform-analytics-cloud/)

Comment: What I need is to combine CLOUD HANA data with ERP Data

Comment: Is your erp running on cloud?

Comment: Is there any other method instead of SLT or Smart Data Integration.
Like creating a destination in Hana side

Comment: I don't think there is. There is cloud connector but this one is sending data cloud to on-premise. You may want to check: https://answers.sap.com/questions/150681/hana-cloud-connector-usage-and-advantages.html